# How do I bind two different data collections into 2 different PanoramaItem listbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox, panorama-control

I have AItems and BItems, want to bind to AListBox in a PanoramaItem and BListBox in another PanoramamItem.

I specified ItemsSource in each ListBox

```
<controls:PanoramaItem>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AItems}" >
      ...
    </ListBox>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
<controls:PanoramaItem 
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BItems}" >
      ...
    </ListBox>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

How do I bind the data to each ListBox from code behind?

I have the Constructor method

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and page load method

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To bind the collections to controls in code-behind :

1) Give the listboxes names
2) in code behind, set <listboxName>.ItemsSource = <collection>

(You should make sure your collections are ObservableCollection<myType> to ensure that if the collection changes, this is reflected in the view.)

for example...

```
<controls:PanoramaItem>
    <ListBox Name="AItemBox" >
      ...
    </ListBox>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
<controls:PanoramaItem 
    <ListBox Name="BItemBox" >
      ...
    </ListBox>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

and then

```
private void BindMyControls()
{
    AItemBox.ItemSource = AItems;
    BItemBox.ItemSource = BItems;
}
```

Then you can call `BindMyControls()` from the most appropriate place, most likely once the collections have been populated.